# Local vs. remote accessing Pi from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, raspbian, mdns

I have a Raspberry Pi with a hat to control my sunscreens. Works very well when I use the normal internet connection.

I have added code to detect when I'm on the local network and even using mDNS / Bonjour I detect the Raspberry Pi from iOS and get it's local IP address. But then if I do a request to the Pi using the local IP address I get a (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824) error. The cause is obvious: the SSL certificate on the Pi has the FQDN in it and of course that is not the same as 192.168.2.13 or whatever.

But then the big question: how to solve this.
One idea could be to make sure from outside the router resolves to my FQDN, from the inside I should make sure that the FQDN resolves to the local address my Pi is on. But the only way I could imagine how I pull that off is making the Pi a DNS and DHCP server. Although I could do that of course I am starting to think that I make it way too difficult and there should be other solutions.

One maybe easier option might be to bring another server process in the air on the pi and if I detect the Pi using bonjour not go through the http(s) route but use the alternative solution (sockets?)? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried directly using `<name-of-your-device>.local` in the URL, and adding a certificate for that name on the Pi? As you'll need to sign it yourself, you'll need to add the signing certificate to your app.

Comment: Some wifi routers will allow connections to the "outside" WAN address from the LAN. Have you tried this?  You may be able to just use the DNS external DNS name regardless of how you are connected.

Comment: I have basically solved it by just adding the FQDN in my routers DNS list and set it to the local ip address. That works of course but it still feels like cheating. I mean what if we would want to make it into a product? The tip by jcaron also should work I think, main disadvantage would be that I need to processes running, that is doable of course but also not very elegant.